# action listener doesnt work

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java swing.

When i want to set an actionlistener to one of the buttons it has to get the textArea content and send that to another class. It doesn't work in a way that i expect.

Instead it works when i change the text area's content, i don't know what's happened?

The first button i named **Button** and the same problem happened when i use another actionlistener inside the Button's actionlistener named **Clac**

here is my code:

```
package FFT;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FFT_Main_Frame extends JFrame {

JLabel label;
JButton button;
TextPanel txtPanel;
JButton Button;
JLabel label1;
//JTextArea[] BoxArray;
makePolynomial mp;
JButton Calc;
Complex[] Nums;
Complex[] Result;
int input;
FFT_Main fft_main;
ShowResult shr;

public FFT_Main_Frame()
{
    super ("F F T");
    //final int input;
    label=new JLabel();
    txtPanel=new TextPanel();
    Button=new JButton("OK");

    label.setText("Please Enter your Polynomial Degree");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(label);
    add(txtPanel);
    add(Button);

    Calc=new JButton("Claculate");



    Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        //Test t;

        //Integer content;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try{
            Integer   content=new   Integer(Integer.parseInt(txtPanel.getTextArea()));
            input=content;
            System.out.println(input);
            //inputt=input;
            mp=new makePolynomial(content);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            add(mp);
            //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(Calc);

            Nums=new Complex[input+1];
            Calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                for(int i=input;i>=0;i--)
                    {
                        Nums[i]=new  Complex(Double.parseDouble(mp.BoxArray[2*(i+1)- 1].getText()),Double.parseDouble(mp.BoxArray[2*i].getText()));
                    }

                    for (int i=0;i<=input;i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(Nums[i]);
                    }
                    fft_main=new FFT_Main();
                    Result=new Complex[input];

                    Result=fft_main.Recursive_FFT(Nums);

                    shr=new ShowResult(Result);

                    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    add(shr,BorderLayout.CENTER);

                    System.out.println("Result\n\n");
                    for (int i=0;i<=input;i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(Result[i]);
                    }

                }
                });



            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Just Numbers! " , "Wrong Value", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
        }
    }
            );
    //Integer k=new Integer(Integer.parseInt(txtPanel.getTextArea()));
    //System.out.println();
    //Nums=new Complex[input+1];





    setSize(600,500);
    setVisible(true);






  }

}
```

makePolynomial class:

```
package FFT;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class makePolynomial extends JPanel{


  JLabel[] label;
  public JTextArea[] BoxArray;
  public static int l;
  public makePolynomial(int i)
  {
      //label=new JLabel();
      BoxArray=new JTextArea[2*(i+1)];
    label=new JLabel[i];
    l=i;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     int b=i;
     for (int x=2*(i+1)-1;x>=0;x-=2)
    {
        BoxArray[x]=new JTextArea(1,3);
        BoxArray[x-1]=new JTextArea(1,3);
         add(BoxArray[x]);
         add(BoxArray[x-1]);

         if (b >=1)
         {
             label[b-1]=new JLabel();
             label[b-1].setText("<html>i X<sup>"+b+"</sup></html>");
            add(label[b-1]);
        }

        if(b==0)
         {
            JLabel l1=new JLabel();
             l1.setText("i");
             add(l1);
         }
         b--;
     }
 }

}
```

ShowResult Class:

```
package FFT;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ShowResult extends JPanel {
JLabel[] label;


public ShowResult(Complex[] c) {


    label=new JLabel[c.length];
    System.out.println("Complex"+c.length);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    for (int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        label[i]=new JLabel();
        label[i].setText("y["+i+"]= "+c[i].toString());

        add(label[i]);

    }




  }



  }
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What does _it doesn't work in a way that i expect_ mean? What do you expect?

Comment: Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Especially provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (focus on **minimal**) to reproduce the issue - your code most likely contains too much stuff which is not required to demonstrate the issue. This is also a general approach to track down issues: reduce the code to the absolute minimum (use a version control system such as git so that you can track your changes).

Comment: i expect  that after button clicked the action listener works entirely but instead after the button clicked nothing happened until  when i want to change the textArea content the action listener works.... i am wondering why the                                                                                         mp=new makePolynomial(content);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            add(mp);                                                                                                    do not work

Comment: Your code is a mess. Please try to follow good naming conventions, to make it more readable. Button is a name for a class, not a variable. Have your variables names begin with lower cases, so we know you're not referring to classes.

Comment: please reformat code, and remove as much code as you can so that we can focus on the problem. Otherwise it is less likely you will get an answer.

Comment: You have a `JButton` named `Button` and another named `button`. This is awful naming. Name your variables descriptively and always starting with a lower-case letter and then CamelCase after that. (So an upper-case letter at the start of each new word in the variable name).

Answer (score 0):

As an example of a runnable program with a smaller part of your code, see here below. To keep it short, I have replaced the `makePolynomial` class by a `JPanel`. I have added code to hide the three initial components in the `actionPerformed` method for `Button`, but I am pretty sure there are much better ways to do this.

Does this program work as you expect on your machine?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ActionListenerBug {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ActionListenerBug().createAndShowGui());
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        // TextPanel is a class?
        JTextPane txtPanel = new JTextPane();
        JButton Button = new JButton("OK");

        label.setText("Please Enter your Polynomial Degree");

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(txtPanel);
        panel.add(Button);

        Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    int input = Integer.parseInt(txtPanel.getText());
                    System.out.println(input);
                    //mp = new makePolynomial(content);
                    JPanel mp = new JPanel();
                    mp.add(new JLabel("input: " + input));

                    // Hide other components for now. Showing a different panel would be
                    // better.
                    label.setVisible(false);
                    txtPanel.setVisible(false);
                    Button.setVisible(false);

                    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    panel.add(mp);
                    //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    JButton Calc = new JButton("Claculate");
                    panel.add(Calc);
                    panel.revalidate();
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Just Numbers! ", 
                                                  "Wrong Value", 
                                                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```